# updating rails image_path dynamically

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using the rails js helper image_path to update an images source using javascript.

The actual string for the new img src path lives inside of a variable and I need to inject that into the image_path string below, which has been giving me problems.

Here is what I'm working with:

Object:

var bike = { image: "bikes/diamondback/diamondback-29-ht.png"}

Image path:

```
$('.ga-recommended-bike').attr('src', "<%= image_path 'bikes/diamondback/diamondback-29-ht.png' %>")
```

I've been trying to do something like this to inject the url into the image path:

```
$('.ga-recommended-bike').attr('src', "<%= image_path `${bike.image}` %>")
```

also tried the non es6 way

```
$('.ga-recommended-bike').attr('src', "<%= image_path " + bike.image + " %>")
```

I think the problem is the intermingling of the rails and js code.

Does anyone know of a good way to solve this using rails and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need the ruby code in the JS?  That probably won't work. But if you must pull data from the dom to render data via js, why not use the ruby code in the view in say a data attribute and use that in the javascript.

```
<div id="my-data-thing", data-image-path="<%= image_path 'bikes/diamondback/diamondback-29-ht.png' %> ></div>
```

Comment: My issue isn't with pulling from the dom. It's that I'm trying to update an image src using javascript and rails' asset pipeline doesn't play well with this type of task. As far as I know, I have to use the javascript helper. Otherwise I could update the src without using the image_path helper at all. If there's another way to accomplish this I'm open to ideas

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to get the string injection to work, but here's how I got to a working solution (that still doesn't answer this question):

I included the full image path url in the object variable. The file this lives in must be .js.erb

```
  var bikes = {
    diamondbackOverdrive29: {
      image: "<%= image_path 'bikes/diamondback/diamondback-29-ht.png' %>",
      price: "",
      make: "",
      model: "",
      features: []
    }
  }
```

Then I'm able to just call bikes.diamondbackOverdrive29.image

So I'm going to have to declare the full image path for each item, but it seems okay for now, and pretty clean still.